# Impedir a inserção, pelo usuário, do mesmo número de CPF em três campos distintos

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Em uma tabela carrego o CPF de paciente, médico e da atendente. Estou tentando impedir que a pessoa consiga agendar colocando os 3 com os mesmos valores. Tipo:

```
INSERT INTO agenda(cpf_atendente, cpf_paciente, cpf_medico, dataAgendamento) 
     VALUES(1837857227, 1837857227, 1837857227, '2020-03-05');
```

Mas não tive sucesso.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `agenda` (
  `cpf_atendente` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `cpf_paciente` INT(11) NOT NULL, 
  `cpf_medico` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `dataAgendamento` DATE NOT NULL,      
  PRIMARY KEY (`cpf_atendente`,`cpf_paciente`,`cpf_medico`,`dataAgendamento`),
   UNIQUE INDEX `unico`(`cpf_paciente`,`cpf_medico`, `cpf_atendente`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`cpf_atendente`)
    REFERENCES `atendente` (`cpf_atendente`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY (`cpf_paciente`)
    REFERENCES `paciente` (`cpf_paciente`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY (`cpf_medico`)
    REFERENCES `medico` (`cpf_medico`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: Informe o SGBD em questão , a solução pode ser uma check constraint ou trigger de validação.

Comment: É MySQL que estou usando

Comment: Eu faria diferente, Criaria um campo chamado cod_key int e autoincremento primary_key, depois Criaria o Index Unique com os três campos cpf_paciente, cpf_medico e cpf_atendente, não controlaria com o campo dataAgendamento pois ele muito mutável... o controle da dataAgendamento pode ser feito na aplicação, pois você pode simplesmente consultar se naquela data e hora já existe agendamento para um determinado medico, o cara não vai conseguir atender 2 ao mesmo tempo... não conheço a aplicação, mas acho que a lógica está te atrapalhando... eu tenho um sistema de agendamento e fiz como acima.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como o @Motta sugeriu, uma solução possível é realizar o controle por meio de **[Trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html#c8808)**.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ValidaTresCPF BEFORE INSERT ON Agenda
FOR EACH ROW
begin
    DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);
    IF (new.cpf_atendente = new.cpf_paciente) and (new.cpf_atendente = new.cpf_medico) THEN
        set msg = "Os 3 CPFs não podem ser iguais.";
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45003' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
   END IF;
END;
```

> **[SIGNAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html)** é a maneira de “retornar” um erro. `SIGNAL` fornece informações de erro a um manipulador, a uma parte externa do
> aplicativo ou ao cliente. Além disso, fornece controle sobre as
> características do erro (número do erro, SQLSTATE valor, mensagem).

Dessa forma, além de evitar a inserção, retorna uma mensagem de erro que pode ser tratada na aplicação.